# Fetch, merge and paginate data from multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I'm working on an application where users have different types of events. Each event type has its own database table/Laravel model. Right now I'm performing multiple database queries to fetch the events from the tables. After that I merge them manually by using for-each loops and creating a uniform structure.

Because the code is really long, I give an example code here:

```
$output = [];
$events1 = EventType1::where('user',$user_id)->get();

foreach ($events1 as $ev1) {
    $output[] = [
        "id" => $ev1->id,
        "date" => $ev1->id,
        "attribute3" => $ev1->attributeA
    ];
}

$events2 = EventType2::where('user',$user_id)->get();

foreach ($events2 as $ev2) {
    $output[] = [
        "id" => $ev2->id,
        "date" => $ev2->id,
        "attribute3" => $ev2->someOtherAttribute
    ];
}

// More fetches here....
// ...
// ...

usort($output, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["date"], $b["date"]);
});

return $output;
```

So right now I want to improve the performance by using Pagination. But the way I fetch the data, I don't think it will work? How can I fetch, merge and paginate all the events the proper way? Is there a way to union all the data using Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

If you want with pagination you can follow this. I have used one of my projects for merging different model data as well as including pagination. If you don't need pagination just ignore pagination method calling part.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

public function events(){

    $events1 = EventType1::where('user',$user_id)->get();
    $events2 = EventType2::where('user',$user_id)->get();

    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection = $collection->merge($events1);
    $collection = $collection->merge($events2);
    $merge = $this->paginate($collection, $limit);
    return $merge;
}

public function paginate($items, $perPage = 10, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

Comment: I can't put both EventTypes in a collection because they don't have the same attributes.

Comment: If other attributes are totally different so the above solution will not work. If you alias attribute name in a common name which you already did in the attribute3 array. so I think that is a good option.